# Codekit 2 + Foundation compiling

Tags: compilation, zurb-foundation, bower, codekit

I just can't get Codekit to compile my files.

I created a New Zurb Foundation project exactly as Bryan did in his video. No errors but for him the page loads with the styles. For me it just loads html but no styles are included except app.css.

Bower succesfully downloads all the files to bower_components. How can I make codekit to compile all files? Do I have to manually move the files from the folder to the root? I'm trying to start with SASS so I don't know how the imports work.

They don't mention any imports or any particular settings here: https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#zurb-foundation

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but enabling the libsass compiler for app.scss seemed to work for me.

Highlight app.scss, then in the right pane, select  "Use the libsass compiler."

Comment: I installed Codekit 2.1.3 instead of 2.1.5. There is apparently a bug according to a changelog

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by changing the output file for app.scss to be /css/app.css. That was the path the the index.html file was looking for.

You'll probably need to create the "css" folder in your project, as it wasn't there for me by default.